# How to TwoWay data-bind nested INotifyPropertyChanged ViewModels to ComboBox inside of ListView in WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, listview, data-binding, combobox, winui-3

I am attempting to implement a proposed solution to my [other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76758236/how-to-force-combobox-in-listview-to-update-when-listview-collection-changes-in/76759438#76759438). The goal is to use databinding in place of handling `ComboBox` `Loaded` events.

I have two nested ViewModels I am trying to databind (similar to [the simplified question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429140/automatically-raise-propertychanged-when-an-inner-object-property-got-changed?rq=3)), where a `ListView` displays a list of the outter ViewModel (`TaskViewModel`) while the `ComboBox` inside of the `ListView` displays a list of the inner ViewModel (`StatusViewModel`), and the `SelectedItem` inside of the `ComboBox` is `TwoWay` databound to the `Status` property on the `TaskViewModel`.

I keep getting an unexpected uncaught exception, which is being cause by the `Set` on `TaskViewModel.Status` setting a null value. When using the Visual Studio StackTrace, all I can find is that this setter is being called from "External Code".

**If I uncomment the commented out code in TaskViewModel.cs, the code runs but the ComboBox binding does nothing.** I implemented the solution to [the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870069/implementing-inotifypropertychanged-for-nested-properties) for nested view models with `INotifyPropertyChanged` on my `TaskViewModel.Status`, but that did not seem to fix my issue.

Where is this null value coming from? I have verified that the list of `MyTask` going into `SetProjectTasks()` never contains a task with `Status` value `null`.

What is the proper way to implement this (list of outer view models bound to `ListView` with nested view model property on that view model being bound to `ComboBox`)? Is my approach wrong?

Page.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="TasksListView"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
          ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyTasks}"
          SelectionMode="None"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="TasksListView_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:TaskViewModel">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ComboBox x:Name="StatusComboBox"
                          Tag="{x:Bind ID, Mode=OneWay}"
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          Margin="0,0,10,0"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectTaskStatuses, ElementName=RootPage}"
                          SelectedValue="{x:Bind Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodels:StatusViewModel">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                                           Margin="0,0,10,0"
                                           Height="10"
                                           Width="10"
                                           StrokeThickness="1">
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Bind Color}"></SolidColorBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <Rectangle.Stroke>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Bind Color}"></SolidColorBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Stroke>
                                </Rectangle>

                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                                           Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Page.xaml.cs

```
public ObservableCollection<StatusViewModel> ProjectTaskStatuses { get; set; }

private ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel> MyTasks { get; set; }

public void SetProjectStatuses(List<Status> statuses)
{
    this.ProjectTaskStatuses.Clear();
    statuses.ForEach(status => this.ProjectTaskStatuses.Add(new StatusViewModel(status)));
}

public void SetProjectTasks(List<MyTask> tasks)
{
    this.MyTasks.Clear();
    tasks.ForEach(task => this.MyTasks.Add(new TaskViewModel(task)));
}
```

TaskViewModel.cs

```
public class TaskViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyTask _model;
    public MyTask Model
    {
        get => new MyTask(this._model) { Status = this._status.Model };
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get => this._model?.ID;
        set
        {
            this._model.ID = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ID));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => this._model?.Name;
        set
        {
            this._model.Name = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    private StatusViewModel _status;
    public Status Status
    {
        get => this._status?.Model;
        set
        {
            // COMMENTED OUT CODE FOR TESTING - THIS IS WHERE THE UNEXPECTED NULL HAPPENS
            //if (value == null)
            //{
            //    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("NULL STATUS BEING SET TO - " + this._model.ID + " " + this._model.Name + " " + this._model.Status.Name);
            //    return;
            //}

            if (this._status != null)
                this._status.PropertyChanged -= StatusChanged;

            this._status = new StatusViewModel(value);

            if (this._status != null)
                this._status.PropertyChanged += StatusChanged;

            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Status));

            void StatusChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e) => this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a bindable property of the viewmodel has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public TaskViewModel(MyTask task)
    {
        this._model = task;
        this._status = new StatusViewModel(task.Status);
    }
}
```

StatusViewModel.cs

```
public class StatusViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Status _model;
    public Status Model
    {
        get => new Status(this._model);
    }

    public string ID
    {
        get => this._model?.ID;
        set
        {
            this._model.ID = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ID));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get => this._model?.Name;
        set
        {
            this._model.Name = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Name));
        }
    }

    public Color Color
    {
        get => this._model.Color;
        set
        {
            this._model.Color = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Color));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Raised when a bindable property of the viewmodel has changed.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public StatusViewModel(Status status)
    {
        this._model = status;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I added the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` NuGet package to my project, and replaced the `MyTask` model as suggested. I also eliminated the `StatusViewModel` entirely and replaced it with just `Status`. This simplified the code, but same problem. I subscribed to the `PropertyChanged` event with a print statement in the handler, and confirm that it is never being fired:

Code behind changes:

```
public partial class TaskViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private MyTask _model;

    public TaskViewModel(MyTask task)
    {
        this._model = task;
    }
}

public void SetProjectTasks(List<MyTask> tasks)
{
    MyTasks.Clear();
    TaskViewModel taskViewModel = new TaskViewModel(task)
    taskViewModel.PropertyChanged += this.ViewModel_PropertyChanged;
    tasks.ForEach(task => this.MyTasks.Add(taskViewModel ));
}

private void TaskViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Confirmed with debugger and print statement this event handler never runs... even when changing the status ComboBox.
        TaskViewModel model = sender as TaskViewModel;
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Model for task: " + model.Model.Name +
            " property " + e.PropertyName +
            " changed to " + model.GetType().GetProperty(e.PropertyName).GetValue(model).ToString());
    }
```

XAML changes:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="StatusComboBox"
                  Tag="{x:Bind Model.ID, Mode=OneWay}"
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  Margin="0,0,10,0"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectTaskStatuses, ElementName=RootPage}"
                  SelectedValue="{x:Bind Model.Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Status">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Rectangle Grid.Column="0"
                           Margin="0,0,10,0"
                           Height="10"
                           Width="10"
                           StrokeThickness="1">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Bind Color}"></SolidColorBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                    <Rectangle.Stroke>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{x:Bind Color}"></SolidColorBrush>
                    </Rectangle.Stroke>
                </Rectangle>

                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           Text="{x:Bind Name}"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Issues:

1. The `ComboBox` is not initialized - there is no selection.
2. Changing  the `ComboBox` (by clicking on it and selecting a different value) does not trigger any code to run.
3. The `ComboBox` data binding appears to be over-writing the `Status` value to `null` at some point. I have confirmed the `MyTask.Status` values being set in `SetProjectTasks()` still never has a null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell with all of this code. These are the 2 issues that I could spot.

- The `ComboBox`'s `ItemsSource` is a collection of `StatusViewModel`s but the `SelectedValue` is bound to a `Status`.
- The `Model` property in the `StatusViewModel` always return a new instance.

This might not be an answer but let me show you something close but with less code by using the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/) NuGet package.

```cs
public class Status
{
    public string? ID { get; internal set; }
    public string? Name { get; internal set; }
    public Color Color { get; internal set; }
}

public class MyTask
{
    public string? ID { get; internal set; }
    public string? Name { get; internal set; }
    public Status? Status { get; set; }
}

public partial class TaskViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private MyTask _model;

    public TaskViewModel(MyTask task)
    {
        this._model = task;
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Status> ProjectTaskStatuses { get; set; } = new();

    private ObservableCollection<TaskViewModel> MyTasks { get; set; } = new();

    public void SetProjectStatuses(List<Status> statuses)
    {
        ProjectTaskStatuses.Clear();
        statuses.ForEach(status => this.ProjectTaskStatuses.Add(status));
    }

    public void SetProjectTasks(List<MyTask> tasks)
    {
        MyTasks.Clear();
        tasks.ForEach(task => this.MyTasks.Add(new TaskViewModel(task)));
    }

    private void SetTasksButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<MyTask> tasks = new();
        Status? defaultStatus = ProjectTaskStatuses.FirstOrDefault();
        tasks.Add(new MyTask { ID = "1", Name = "Task 1", Status = defaultStatus });
        tasks.Add(new MyTask { ID = "2", Name = "Task 2", Status = defaultStatus });
        tasks.Add(new MyTask { ID = "3", Name = "Task 3", Status = defaultStatus });
        SetProjectTasks(tasks);
    }

    private void SetStatusOptionsButton_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Status> statuses = new();
        statuses.Add(new Status { ID = "1", Name = "Status 1", Color = Colors.Red });
        statuses.Add(new Status { ID = "2", Name = "Status 2", Color = Colors.Green });
        statuses.Add(new Status { ID = "3", Name = "Status 3", Color = Colors.Blue });
        SetProjectStatuses(statuses);
    }
}
```

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <StackPanel
        Grid.Row="0"
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button
            Click="SetStatusOptionsButton_Click"
            Content="Set status options" />
        <Button
            Click="SetTasksButton_Click"
            Content="Set taks" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ListView
        x:Name="TasksListView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyTasks}"
        SelectionMode="None">

        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:TaskViewModel">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ComboBox
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=RootPage, Path=ProjectTaskStatuses}"
                        SelectedItem="{x:Bind Model.Status, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Status">
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ComboBox>
                    <TextBlock
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Text="{x:Bind Model.Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I adjusted my project as suggested - definitely simplified my code! Thank you! Did not seem to make a difference with the problem though. I updated the question to reflect this.

Comment: I actually implemented a sample app for this answer and it works. Can you make sure the your page is named "RootPage" and there's no misspelling in the binding code?

Comment: As a sanity check, I copy and pasted the code from this solution into a new project - and it did indeed work. I then did a side-by-side comparison with my original code, and caught two differences: 1) I bound to `SelectedValue` instead of `SelectedItem` on the `ComboBox`, and 2) I did not have `Mode=OneWay` on any bindings in the `ComboBox`. I changed those to match this solution - neither fixed it. This solution from scratch works while my original code does not.

Comment: I am wondering if this is an issue with references. This solution assigns a `Status` to each `Task` using the same references that are placed into the `ProjectTaskStatuses`. My original code does not, as I am sourcing the data from different API calls. Next I will try updating my original code to see if I can similarly assign the `Status` property using the same references that I place into `MyProjectStatuses`.

Comment: I have confirmed, the references were the issue. I updated my original code so that I explicitly overwrote the references to the `Status` objects in the `MyTask.Status` member so that they were from the set of references (`Status` objects) placed into `ProjectTaskStatuses`. That fixed the data binding, and now the `ComboBox` are initialized properly. Now the only remaining issue, is that changing the value in the `ComboBox` does not raise the `TaskViewModel.PropertyChanged` event of the bound viewmodel.

Comment: I accepted this answer because it has been incredibly helpful! The issue in the comments above still remains to be solved - but I plan to update this with a link to an answer once I figure it out (unless someone else beats me to it!)